# two google charts on one page with super proxy

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

How can I have two google charts on one page? I'm using super proxy to get JSON table from google analytics API.

Currently, only the first chart (Table) is shown. Missing the second chart.

My code is attached below. I'm not so familiar with the API things. I checked some solutions, but all have data locally instead of from online sources, e.g., spreadsheet, JSON table.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
    <!--Load the AJAX API-->
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src='https://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={"modules":[{"name":"visualization","version":"1"}]}'>
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['table','geochart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

        function drawCountriesTable() {
            var CountriesTableWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            "containerId": "CountriesTable_div",
            "dataSourceUrl": "https://top3dapp.appspot.com/query?id=agpzfnRvcDNkYXBwchULEghBcGlRdWVyeRiAgICAgICACgw&format=data-table-response",
            "refreshInterval": 43200,
            "chartType": "Table",
            "options": {
                "showRowNumber" : true
                }
            });

            CountriesTableWrapper.draw();
        }

        function drawRegionsMap() {
            var RegionsMapWrapper = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
            "containerId": "RegionsMap_div",
            "dataSourceUrl": "https://top3dapp.appspot.com/query?id=agpzfnRvcDNkYXBwchULEghBcGlRdWVyeRiAgICAvKGCCgw&format=data-table-response",
            "refreshInterval": 43200,
            "chartType": "GeoChart",
            "options": {
                "displayMode": 'markers',
                "colorAxis": { "colors": ['#A9DEF2', '#048DC7'] }
                }
            });

            RegionsMapWrapper.draw();
        }

        function drawVisualization() {
            drawCountriesTable();
            drawRegionsMap();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Countries</h2>
    <div id="CountriesTable_div" style="margin:auto;width:630px;"></div>
    <h2>Regions</h2>
    <div id="RegionsMap_div" style="margin:auto;width:630px;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: This works fine in jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/rtrjLsfw/

Comment: Yes. It works now. It is a bug in super proxy (https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-super-proxy/issues/17)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The is a bug of super proxy. Bug report see:
https://github.com/googleanalytics/google-analytics-super-proxy/issues/17

Following the steps as suggested on github:

1. Open query_helper.py
2. Go to the method 'GetPublicEndpointResponse'
3. In line 395, you should see

   `transformed_response_content = response.get('transformed_content')`

Change that line to:

```
transformed_response_content = transform.Transform(response_content)
```

4. Test/Deploy updates